# How to count the amount of times a certain word appears in my python output? (Multiple Lines/Long List)

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

so I am doing some sentiment analysis on a bunch of reviews (100,000 reviews which I data cleaned down to 9,000). I successfully analyzed each review into Positive and Negative. Now when I print my results, it prints each of the reviews and says "Positive" or "Negative". Here is a simplified results of my output https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftUu6.jpg

Now I want to count the amount of times "Positive" appears and amount of times "Negative" appears. I tried a bunch of different ways but the furthest I've gotten is to count only the first line of my output.

Here's one of the ways I've tried:

`x = sentimentprediction.count('Positive')`

`print(x)`

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: if sentimentprediction == 'Positive': positivte_count += 1, can't you  just add this line after the print() statement ? I'm not sure if this answers the question.